# ActorTestKit the shutdown method does not work properly

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following test:

```
final class DetectorSpec extends BddSpec {

  private val sap = Container.sap()
  private val kafka = Container.kafka()

  sap.start()
  kafka.start()


  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    sap.stop()
    kafka.stop()
  }

  private def withKafkaAndSapOnline(testCode: TestProbe[ServerEvent] => Unit)
  : Unit = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""akka.actor.default-dispatcher = {
            type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
          }
          akka.actor.testkit.typed.single-expect-default = 0s
          akka.loglevel = DEBUG
          kafka {
           servers = "${kafka.getBootstrapServers}"
           zookeeper = "${kafka.getMappedPort(2181)}"
         }
         sap {
           server = "ws://${sap.getContainerIpAddress}:${sap.getMappedPort(8080)}"
         }""")

    val testKit = ActorTestKit("DetectorSystem1", config)
    testKit.spawn(DetectorSupervisor.create(), "DetectorSupervisor")
    val inbox = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver")
    testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox.ref)
    testCode(inbox)
    testKit.shutdownTestKit()

  }


  private def withKafkaAndSapOffline(testCode: (TestProbe[ServerEvent], TestProbe[ServerEvent]) => Unit)
  : Unit = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""akka.actor.default-dispatcher = {
            type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
          }
          akka.actor.testkit.typed.single-expect-default = 0s
          akka.loglevel = DEBUG
          kafka {
            servers = "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
            zookeeper = "2181"
          }
          sap {
            server = "ws://127.0.0.1"
          }""")

    val testKit = ActorTestKit("DetectorSystem2", config)
    testKit.spawn(DetectorSupervisor.create(), "DetectorSupervisor")
    val inbox1 = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver1")
    val inbox2 = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver2")
    testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox1.ref)
    testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox2.ref)

    testCode(inbox1, inbox2)
    testKit.shutdownTestKit()
  }

  private def withKafkaOfflineSapOnline(testCode: TestProbe[ServerEvent] => Unit)
  : Unit = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""akka.actor.default-dispatcher = {
            type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
          }
          akka.actor.testkit.typed.single-expect-default = 0s
          akka.loglevel = DEBUG
          kafka {
            servers = "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
            zookeeper = "2181"
          }
          sap {
            server = "ws://${sap.getContainerIpAddress}:${sap.getMappedPort(8080)}"
          }""")

    val testKit = ActorTestKit("DetectorSystem3", config)
    val inbox = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver")
    testKit.spawn(DetectorSupervisor.create(), "DetectorSupervisor")
    testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox.ref)

    testCode(inbox)
    testKit.shutdownTestKit()
  }

  private def withKafkaOnlineSapOffline(testCode: TestProbe[ServerEvent] => Unit)
  : Unit = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""akka.actor.default-dispatcher = {
            type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
          }
          akka.actor.testkit.typed.single-expect-default = 0s
          akka.loglevel = DEBUG
          kafka {
            servers = "${kafka.getBootstrapServers}"
            zookeeper = "${kafka.getMappedPort(2181)}"
          }
          sap {
            server = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080"
          }""")

    val testKit = ActorTestKit("DetectorSystem4", config)
    testKit.spawn(DetectorSupervisor.create(), "DetectorSupervisor")
    val inbox = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver")
    testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox.ref)

    testCode(inbox)
    testKit.shutdownTestKit()

  }


  feature("Detect Kafka and SAP availability") {
    info("As a technical user, I want to be notified in real time, if Kafka and SAP is up and running or not.")
    scenario("SAP and Kafka are available") {
      withKafkaAndSapOnline { inbox =>
        Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
        When("I am receive the state message")
        Then("it should contain `SAP and Kafka are online`")
        inbox.fishForMessage(5.second){
          case ServerOfflineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.continue
          case ServerOnlineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.complete
          case _ =>
            FishingOutcomes.fail("Unexpected message")
        }
      }
    }

    scenario("SAP is online and Kafka is offline") {
      withKafkaOfflineSapOnline { inbox =>
        Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
        When("I am receive the state message")
        Then("it should contain `Kafka is offline`")
        inbox.fishForMessage(5.second){
          case ServerOfflineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.complete
          case _ =>
            FishingOutcomes.fail("Unexpected message")
        }
      }
    }

    scenario("SAP is offline and Kafka is online") {
      withKafkaOnlineSapOffline { inbox =>
        Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
        When("I am receive the state message")
        Then("it should contain `SAP is offline`")
        inbox.fishForMessage(5.second){
          case ServerOfflineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.complete
          case _ =>
            FishingOutcomes.fail("Unexpected message")
        }
      }
    }

    scenario("SAP and Kafka are offline") {
      withKafkaAndSapOffline { (inbox1, inbox2) =>
        Given("I am registering two listeners")
        When("I am receive the state message")
        Then("it should contain `Kafka and SAP are offline`")
        inbox1.fishForMessage(5.second){
          case ServerOfflineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.complete
          case _ =>
            FishingOutcomes.fail("Unexpected message")
        }
        inbox2.fishForMessage(5.second){
          case ServerOfflineApproved =>
            FishingOutcomes.complete
          case _ =>
            FishingOutcomes.fail("Unexpected message")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see after every test, it will shutdown the `ActorTestKit`. But sometimes it freezes, that means, I've got the following message:

```
[DEBUG] [07/19/2019 20:37:57.788] [DetectorSystem3-akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher-11] [akka://DetectorSystem3/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Attempting connection to [localhost/127.0.0.1:32846]
[DEBUG] [07/19/2019 20:37:57.789] [DetectorSystem3-akka.io.pinned-dispatcher-2] [akka://DetectorSystem3/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Connection established to [localhost:32846]
[INFO] [07/19/2019 20:37:58.807] [ScalaTest-run-running-DetectorSpec] [akka://DetectorSystem3/user/DetectorSupervisor/KafkaActor/KafkaStreamer] !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Shutdown KafkaDetectorActor !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[INFO] [07/19/2019 20:37:58.810] [ScalaTest-run-running-DetectorSpec] [akka://DetectorSystem3/user/DetectorSupervisor/SapActor/SapStreamer] !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Shutdown SapDetectorActor !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

and the `ActorTestKit` never shuts down.

Here is the evidence:

[image]

It is just running and running...
How to stop it?

Comment: Hard to guess without a minimal reproducible example, but I would guess not following the async flow might have something to do with it: when you send a message to actor it will be asynchronously triggered, its potential response as well. Actor system shutdown is also asynchronous. So, you should either use some measure of performing one operation after the previous one ended (e.g. `Future`) or using something like `Await.result` to block until asynchronous operation ended.

Comment: The fact that you trigger next things while previous `Future` might be just started executing on another thread could be the source of some of what you see.